# Replace option values

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I'm trying to **update** the options after 3 seconds.

In my HTML I have the code that generates the options.

```
<select
  ng-model="selectedOperator"
  ng-options="operator as operator.name for operator in operators">
</select>
```

And in the same HTML, I have

```
$(function() { 
  $('select').material_select(); 
});
```

that initializes the Materialize dropdown.

In my Javascript:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

  // initialize old(first) values
  $scope.operators = [
    { value: 1, name: 'Old-One' }, 
    { value: 2, name: 'Old-Two' }
  ];

  $scope.selectedOperator = null; // no default selected value

  // after three seconds, replace the old value with new one.
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.operators = [{ value: 10, name: 'New Awesome' }];
    // reinitialize the materialize select.
    $('select').material_select();
  }, 3000);
});
```

However it's not being updated, it's still generating the old value.
In the HTML, the value of `{{ operators }}` is the new value.

I'm new to Angular, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

**Update**: I'm like 70% sure they don't play well with each other, made a temporary fix by replacing select with radio button.

Comment: i have tried its working, are you getting any logs?

Comment: Don't use jQuery with angular. have a look at this directive: https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize

Comment: @AppuAmruth I'm not getting any log

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedOperator">
      <option ng-repeat="operator in operators" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Well, I stumbled upon a post in stackoverflow that strongly suggested not to use ng-repeat in options. ng-options is meant to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample example you can change this values later, its working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function() { 
                $('select').material_select(); 
            });

            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.operators = [
                       { value: 1, name: 'Old-One' }, 
                       { value: 2, name: 'Old-Two' }
                     ];
                $scope.selectedOperator = null; // no default selected value

                   // after three seconds, replace the old value with new one.
                   $timeout(function() {
                     $scope.operators = [{ value: 10, name: 'New Awesome' }];
                     // reinitialize the materialize select.
                     $('select').material_select();
                   }, 3000);

           });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
        <h1>Angular JS Application</h1>
        <select ng-model="selectedOperator" ng-options="operator as operator.name for operator in operators">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```